# ".definitions is not a valid plugin property" when adding a new plugin to webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, webpack-5, babel-loader

I have a pretty simple webpack config file that looks like this:

```
                        plugins: [
                            ["@babel/transform-runtime", { regenerator: true }],
                            "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { loose: true }],
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { loose: true }],
                            "babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements",
                         ],
```

with other things on the top and bottom, and I added the following:

```
                        plugins: [
                            ["@babel/transform-runtime", { regenerator: true }],
                            "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { loose: true }],
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { loose: true }],
                            "babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements",
                            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                                process: 'process/browser',
                            }),
                         ],
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/colelashley/waveterm/src/index.ts: .definitions is not a valid Plugin property
- Maybe you meant to use
"plugins": [
  ["babel-plugin-jsx-control-statements", {
  "definitions": {
    "process": "process/browser"
  }
}]
]
To be a valid plugin, its name and options should be wrapped in a pair of brackets
```

I feel like it has something to do with using the wrong brackets or something like that
Anyone know how I can fix this?
Thanks